# How to prevent Laravel from returning htmlEntities in JSON data?

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

How can I change my controller to return html content with entities as a string?

I'm receiving html with html entities in one of my callback values for examples

```
{content: "&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;PART TIME MAINTENANCE&lt;/strong&gt;"}
```

I think the solution involves using this.

```
HTML::decode('&lt;h1&gt;Hello&lt;/h1&gt;');
```

Here is what my controller is doing, I don't quite understand how to make it return what I want.

```
class JobController extends Controller{
public function index(){
    $dt = Carbon::now();
    return Response::json(Jobs::where("page_location","=","InternalJobPosting")->where("active","=","1")->where('start_date',"<=",$dt)->where("end_date",">=",$dt)->get(),200);
}
public function show($id){
    return Response::json(Jobs::where("id","=",$id)->first(),200);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time I figured out I could map the data returned into an array and transform the html entities using html_entity_decode().

```
public function index(){
    $dt = Carbon::now();
    $jobs = Jobs::where("page_location","=","InternalJobPosting")->where("active","=","1")->where('start_date',"<=",$dt)->where("end_date",">=",$dt)->get()
    ->map(function ($job) {
        return [
            'id'=>$job->id,
            'active'=>$job->active,
            'content'=>$job->content,
            'category'=>html_entity_decode($job->category),
            'page_location'=>$job->page_location,
            'page_title'=>$job->page_title,
            'start_date'=>$job->start_date,
            'end_date'=>$job->end_date,
        ];
    });


    return Response::json($jobs,200);
}
public function show($id){

    $job = Jobs::where("id","=",$id)->get()
        ->map(function ($job) {
        return [
            'id'=>$job->id,
            'active'=>$job->active,
            'content'=>html_entity_decode($job->content),
            'category'=>$job->category,
            'page_location'=>$job->page_location,
            'page_title'=>$job->page_title,
            'start_date'=>$job->start_date,
            'end_date'=>$job->end_date,
        ];
    });
    return Response::json($job->first(),200);
}
```